# reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length is not working for some pdfs

Tags: reactjs

Its not working for some pdfs. It's working for most pdfs. Is there any other way to write this?
Fullcode

```
let blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        console.log("Blob :" + blob)
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log("File URL :" + fileURL);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
        reader.onloadend = function(){
        var window.pages = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s*]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
          console.log('Number of Pages:', window.pages );
          }
```

I can't share the pdf as it is related to my work. But it's a chinese document , a bill.

Comment: for which type of pdf it is not working ? and for which pdf it is working can u specify that?

Comment: I was messing around and this  worked 
`var window.pages =  reader1.result.match(/\/Type[\]*\/Page[^s]/i).length;
`
Can you tell me what exactly is different here?